# Is there such thing as a SuperDrive enclosure?

Tags: hardware-recommendation, optical-drive, unibody

The [OWC Data Doubler](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Other%20World%20Computing/DDAMBS0GB/) allows you to remove the SuperDrive of a MacBook or MacBook Pro and install a secondary drive. This leaves you with two drives in your Mac laptop, and a SuperDrive sitting on your desk. Is there any sort of SuperDrive enclosure that would allow you to put a SuperDrive inside of it, and then plug into your computer via USB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I have [this one](http://www.byteccusa.com/product/enclosure/DVD-100/DVD-100.htm).  I got it at Fry's in exchange for one by sabrent that didn't work with my mid-2010 superdrive. This new one works just fine with my removed superdrive on 10.6.4, even though the box says it's compatible with basically every version of windows but does not mention OS X.

The one caveat... it comes with a wall adapter for powering the driver rather than a second usb cable. However, I have a USB to male power cable. I plan to remove the power connector and swap it for the connector that is on the plug in adapter that came with the enclosure. The adapter just outputs 5V 2000mA, so I don't see any reason why a straight USB connection wouldn't work just fine.

Check out the MCE Optibay alternatives thread on macrumors.com:

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=680228&page=40

Answer (score 1):

Yes, OWC [sells one](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/Other%20World%20Computing/VLSS9TOPTU2) that can be purchased in a bundle with the Data Doubler. MCE also bundles one with their Optibay product.